# If $f=a_{0}+a_{1}x+...+a_{n}x^{n}\in Z[x]$ has a rational root $r/s$, how to prove $r|a_0$ and $s|a_n$?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

Let $f(x)=a_{0}+a_{1}x+...+a_{n}x^{n}\in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ be a polynomial with integer coefficients, and suppose that $r/s\in \mathbb{Q}$ is a rational root of $f$. Assume that $r$ and $s$ are relatively prime. Prove that $r|a_{0}$ and $s|a_{n}$.

First thing comes into my mind is to plug in the root, but I could find any relation between coefficients and the root.

Comment: Plugging in the root and multiplying through by $s^n$ gives a sum the first $n$ terms of which are obviously multiples of $s$. Hence $a_n$ must be a multiple of $s$.

Comment: Lookup the rational root theorem.

Answer (score 1):

By hypothesis $r/s$ is a rational root of $f$, so we have:
$$f(r/s)=a_{0}+a_{1}(r/s)+...+a_{n}(r/s)^{n}=0.$$

If we multiply by $s^n$ we get $s^{n}a_{0}+s^{n-1}a_{1}r+\ldots sa_{n-1}r+a_{n}r=0$.

Then $s^{n-1}a_{1}r+\ldots a_{n}r=-s^{n}a_{0}$. Thus $r|s^{n}a_{0}$, since $r$ and $s$ are coprime we get that $r|a_{0}$. On the other hand, $s^{n}a_{0}+s^{n-1}a_{1}r+\ldots sa_{n-1}r=-a_{n}r$, so $s|a_{n}r$, again because $r$ and $s$ are coprime we deduce that $s|a_{n}$.